# How to completely copy Grafana dashboard(s) from one server to other server

Tags: grafana

I have 20 plus dashboards in Grafana hosting at Server1. We acquired another server and we did installed same version of Grafana on Server2 machine.

I want to know is this possible that i can completely clone Server-1 Grafana instance along with all dashboards to Server2?

As of now Grafana only supports one by one dashboard import and export.

One other possibility i am thinking is to copy all Grafana files/directories from Server-1 to server-2 using standard SCP command. But i am not sure which files do i need to copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the built-in sqlite3 database, then you can indeed just copy your `data` directory and `conf/custom.ini` to the new server and that will include all your dashboards, plugins, etc.  In that setup the database is contained in `data/grafana.db` under your grafana installation.

Comment: When using their .deb: `DATA_DIR=/var/lib/grafana`

Answer (score 5):

You can use **wizzy** to copy dashboards from one server to another.

Install wizzy using instructions at
https://grafana-wizzy.com/home/getting-started/

Then run the following commands:

Set config for server 1:

```
wizzy set grafana envs local1 url http://server1:3000
wizzy set grafana envs local1 username admin
wizzy set grafana envs local1 password admin
```

Set config for server 2:

```
wizzy set grafana envs local2 url http://server2:3000
wizzy set grafana envs local2 username admin
wizzy set grafana envs local2 password admin
```

Copy from server 1 to server 2:

```
wizzy set context grafana local1
wizzy import dashboards
wizzy set context grafana local2
wizzy export dashboards
```

Your dashboards should be copied now from server 1 to server 2. If there are any issues, please open a GitHub issue on https://github.com/grafana-wizzy/wizzy/issues

Comment: Which server to execute `wizzy set context grafana local1;
wizzy import dashboards;
wizzy set context grafana local2;wizzy export dashboards`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple Perl script to export all Dashboards. Just change the first two variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $Grafana= "www.Agendare.MX:3000";
my $Auth= "API token goes here.";

my @List=`curl -sH "Authorization: Bearer $Auth" 'http://$Grafana/api/search' | jq .[].uid -S`;

mkdir "dashexpo";
foreach my $Uid (@List) {
    $Uid=~ s/["\n]//g;

    my $Title=`curl -sH "Authorization: Bearer $Auth" 'http://$Grafana/api/dashboards/uid/$Uid' | jq .dashboard.title`;
    my @Dashboard=`curl -sH "Authorization: Bearer $Auth" 'http://$Grafana/api/dashboards/uid/$Uid' | jq .dashboard -S --tab`;
    $Title=~ s/["\n]//g;
    print "Exporting $Uid: $Title\n";

    $Title=~ s/ /_/g;
    my $File= "dashexpo/$Title\.json";
    open(FH, ">$File");
    print FH @Dashboard;
    close(FH);
    }
```